# Does Capybara clean its cookies after each request?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara

When I run this spec

```
describe "as wrong user" do
        let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }
        let(:wrong_user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user, email: "wrong@example.com") }
        before { sign_in user }

        describe "submitting a GET request to the Users#edit action" do
            before { get edit_user_path(wrong_user) }
            specify { expect(response).to redirect_to(root_url) }
        end
    end
```

I get this error

> Expected response to be a redirect to http://www.example.com/ but was a redirect to http://www.example.com/signin.

But I thought that after calling this

```
before { sign_in user }
```

User should be logged in. Why does that happen?

Btw, here is sign_in method

```
def sign_in(user, options={})
 visit signin_path
 fill_in "Email",    with: user.email
 fill_in "Password", with: user.password
 check "Remember me"
 click_button "Sign in"
end
```

Comment: Everything in that spec screams it's testing to see what happens if it's the wrong user for the resource. Regardless of the failure you should make the test look like what it's testing. Does the sign on work?

Comment: @DaveNewton, sign_in works, and user is logged in until I call "get edit_user_path(wrong_user)", after that cookies[:remember_token] are null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are using both the capybara dsl (`visit` and so on) and request specs. The latter, being based on rails integration test has its own methods (get, post etc.) of sending requests.

Both of these track state such as cookies across multiple requests but they are completely separate: mixing the two only causes confusion. Capybara however doesn't give you a response object, but should be able to use `page.current_url` to check that the redirect has happened.

Alternatively leave your example as is, but change your sign_in helper to use the `post` method to submit the signing data.

Recent versions of rspec try to help you avoid this by not creating by default specs that have both of the DSLs builtin and instead have separate spec types (spec/api and spec/features) for each (see [here](http://blog.plataformatec.com.br/2012/06/improving-the-integration-between-capybara-and-rspec/)).

Comment: http://blog.plataformatec.com.br/2012/06/improving-the-integration-between-capybara-and-rspec/ provides a bit more detail on the difference between `get` and `visit`

Comment: Thanks - I had a vague memory of seeing something like that before but couldn't find it.

Comment: @FrederickCheung,thank you very much! I will keep in mind your comment about separation of DSL's. 
Btw, I've figured out what is happening.
The whole point is in "before" block. I don'n know why, but each Capybara request(such as visit or get) has its own clean session with a clean cookies if you call them in "before block". And I have no idea why. I think this block was created for some other purposes

Comment: That's not the case, the point is that `get` doesn't make a capybara request at all

Comment: @FrederickCheung, I'm such a noob. Capybara requests and rspec request are separate, you're right. I've just changed sign_in method to use rspec post and all is working now. Thank you, you're the best!

Answer (score 0):

#### You need to maintain session

```
session = Capybara::Session.new(:webkit, my_rack_app)
  session.fill_in "Email",    with: user.email
  session.fill_in "Password", with: user.password
end
session.click_button 'Sign in'
```

Read more about Capybara here: http://www.rubydoc.info/github/jnicklas/capybara/master/Capybara/Session